# What are blue long-dashed lines on a French topo?

Tags: maps, topographical-maps

[image: topo]

On a topographic map of Chamonix I noticed these thick long-dashed (and sometimes dotted) blue lines. They appear to connect huts, settlements, and some arbitrary points. They tend to follow glaciers.

What are these? ski tours?

Comment: Your image doesn’t seem to have linked or uploaded properly

Comment: From my experience — yes, these are ski-tours. I don't have anything more authoritative though.

Comment: This looks like a ski tour with the dashed lines showing the parts that can be skinned on the ascent and the dotted showing the foot sections. At least this is how it is done on the swiss maps

Comment: But where does lead to? At the top it just ends. But I see there are ice cliffs on the map, so perhaps people go there for ice climbing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Cartes IGN map of the Chamonix area, the map key shows the blue lines as "Cross-country or high mountain skiing route". The footpath lines are shown as solid red lines or dashed red lines when "out of footpath" so presumably the dashed line indicate a footpath route which is not visible on the ground. To me this would imply sold blue lines are "Cross-country or high mountain skiing route" which can be seen on the ground and dashed blue lines show the route taken by the "Cross-country or high mountain skiing route" but it cannot be seen on the ground.